# Position of Floating Button is not true in some devices, example for Samsung S3 and Nexus 6

Tags: button, floating

I create Floating Button in my app:

```
 <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/add_fab_detail_activity"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_white"
        fab:backgroundTint="@color/FABNormal"
        fab:rippleColor="@color/FABPressed" />
```

When test on SamSung S3 and Nexus 6, I see position of Fab is different on these divices. I think Position in S3 is false! Please help me!

[image]

Answer (score 0):

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
                    mParamsAddButton.setMargins(mMapView.getWidth() - mAddFab.getWidth()/2, mMapView.getHeight()*3/4, 0, 0);
                } else {
                    mParamsAddButton.setMargins(mMapView.getWidth() - mAddFab.getWidth()/2, mMapView.getHeight()/2, 0, 0);  
                }
```